# Entity Framework: One to Many relationship

Tags: sql, json, entity-framework, database-design, relational-database

I have a design problem with regards to Entity Framework model relationship

I have this model in the edmx
[image: EF Diagram]

**Business Rule:**

A `Participant` can have multiple `Roles` so I create a relationship table `ParticipantRoles` that has 1-to-Many relationship on the `Participant` and the `Role` table

**The Problem**:
  In order to get the Participant's Role value, I have to drill down through `Participant->ParticipantRole->Role`  (see JSON output below)

[image]

**The Question:**

In EF, how to design the table relationship to bypass the ParticipantsRole table. I want to access the Role in something like this `Particant.Role` and not `Participant.ParticipantsRole.Role`

Comment: As I understand it, if you remove the Id from the PareticipantsRole table, the relationship will be automatically mapped the way you want it to be.  The automatic mapping doesn't occur when the relationship table has other columns than the keys of the tables that it's joining.

Comment: if I remove the ParticipantsRole.Id, im getting Table [dbo].[ParticipantsRoles] does not have a clustered index.  Clustered indexes are required for inserting data in this version of SQL Server

Comment: does EF support clustered Index?

Comment: by the way, Im using SQL Azure

Comment: Try removing id and creating a composite primary key on remaining fields.

Comment: You said that _A Participant can have multiple Roles_ so what will be the meaning of Particant.Role? Is Particant.Role a collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say *A `Participant` can have multiple `Role`s*. And of course, a `Role` can have multiple `Participant`s. So basically this is a many-to-many association.

Entity Framework will only map pure many-to-many associations (without connecting class) when the junction table only has two foreign keys. In your case, if the table `ParticipantsRole` only would have had a primary key consisting of `ParticipantId` and `RoleId` *at the time of generating the model* the class `ParticipantsRole` would not have been created. You would have had `Participant.Roles` and `Role.Participants` as navigation properties.

However, the model has been generated with `ParticipantsRole` and you want to get rid of it. (Or not, I'll get back to that).

This is what you can do:

- Remove `ParticipantRoles` from the class diagram.
- Modify the database table `ParticipantRoles` so it only has the two FK columns, that both form the primary key.
- Update the model from the database and select `ParticipantsRole` in the Add tab.

This should give you a model with a pure many-to-many association.

However, think twice before you do this. M2m associations have a way of evolving into 1-m-1association (as you've got now). The reason is that sooner or later the need is felt to record data *about* the association, so the junction table must have more fields and stops being a pure junction table. In your case I can imagine that one day participant's roles must have a fixed order, or one marked as default. It can be a major overhaul to change a m2m association into 1-m-1 in a production environment. - Something to consider...